# Sort datagridview asc to selected combobox item

Tags: vb.net

On my form I have a `combobox` with values from the `dgv` columns

When I select one value in the combobox it should sort by that column in the datagridview

This code doesn't help:

```
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Under sorting I mean on sort like this by column

This way I can sort by the column I want (index)

```
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: How do you fill that `ComboBox`? `SelectedValue` only works if there's a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

I need to use `.SelectedIndex` instead

```
.SelectedValue
```

Comment: This will only work if the `ComboBox` values are exactly the same and are in the same order than the `DataGridView` columns. BTW (and off-topic) did you asked the question just to answer it yourself? Or you found the answer right after posting it?

Comment: Why would i do that. Post your answer same as mine and i will accept it .